# Incompatibility of caption and cleveref package

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, incompatibility, cleveref

The following code produced a `TeX capacity exceeded` error

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Text
  \label{fig:figures:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If either caption or cleverref are not loaded the error does not happen.

Versions are:

```
caption.sty    2011/11/10 v3.2e Customizing captions (AR)
cleveref.sty    2011/10/24{} v0.18{} Intelligent cross-referencing
```

I have contacted the authors of both packages, but if someone here can provide an intermediate solution I would appreciate it.

Comment: This may be related to the recent update to the `cleveref` package. (The date is late October 2011, but I believe it was uploaded to CTAN just a few days ago.) I've noticed similar problems since the update but haven't had the time yet to contact Toby Cubitt (the author of the `cleveref` package).

Comment: Yes, I stripped the code to produce a minimum code example.

Comment: 1. An update to the cleveref package is already on it's way to CTAN. 2. I haven't tried it myself but loading the `caption` package after the `cleveref` package should help if waiting for the new version of `cleveref` is not an option.

Comment: the update (cleveref 0.18.1) is already on www.tex.ac.uk and (99% certainly) on dante.ctan.org

Comment: Merry Christmas

Comment: Thanks all, I closed it as "too localized" now, so that it is concluded here. Please feel free to flag it if there is anything left.